# Autolayout Error with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a TableView and I specify the height for each cell using the delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

When I rotate the view I get this error that I don't quite understand.

It can't satisfy the constraint below and breaks it to continue.

```
"<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x8e8d040 UITableView:0x9423400.contentHeight{id: 213} == -1568.000000>"
```

Does anyone know what is happening and why I'm breaking this constraint?

Answer (score 22):

**UPDATE**: This issue is no longer relevant in iOS 8, which adds support for self-sizing cells. It is still relevant for iOS 7 however.

**Original answer (iOS 7)**:

Greg's answer definitely worked for me - I needed to debug my tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: method. I did some debugging and some quick experiments and here are some things I learned:

1. **Don't use UITableViewAutomaticDimension** in the estimated **row** methods. This constant is for the header and footer methods. I guess I wasn't paying enough attention when I read the documentation :) **UPDATE**: UITableViewAutomaticDimension can now be used for row heights in iOS 8, part of the self-sizing cells functionality.
2. Estimating row height of 1.0 results in an exception: "NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'table view row height must not be negative...'" Estimating less than 1.0 has strange results as well.
3. Estimating between 2.0 and the actual works just fine without any exceptions (although 2.0 is probably a bad choice for optimization reasons - you want to be as close to actual as possible).
4. The constraint exception only occurs when the **estimated row height is greater than the actual row height**. The closer you are to the actual, the less likely the exception will occur. How far off your estimate can be before getting the exception seems to be related to several different factors: actual row height, the position of the row, etc.

Comment: +1 for #4. FWIW this constraint exception occurs in iOS 7 but not in 8.

Comment: @RichardShin Thanks for the note. I updated my answer to say the functionality has changed greatly in iOS 8.

Comment: The second case is actual up to iOS 10 inclusive. It was fixed in iOS 11. A quick sample: https://github.com/OlesyaS/UITableView-ios10-crash/blob/master/table/ViewController.m

Comment: Thank you so much @SoVa_ you just saved me a TON of grief

Answer (score 12):

tl;dr: Look for **actual** height values drastically different than what you ***estimated***.  Or **actual** values that are negative or `0`.

---

I just spent a few minutes debugging this constraint exception. I have a `UITableView` with cells, section headers, and section footers. Each of these had the iOS 7 `estimatedHeightFor` messages defined, returning a `static const` value. I removed cells, headers, and footers, one at a time until I determined the issue was coming from the footer (not important if you don't have footers, please read on).

If I eliminated `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:`, the exception disappeared. In my `heightForFooterInSection:`, there is one path in which the height of the footer would be `0`.  When I restored the `estimatedHeight` message and eliminated the code path for an actual height of `0`, the exception also went away. I replaced `0` with `22` and decreased this value all the way to 12 before the exception reappeared.

Regardless, I need the height of the footer to be `0` (I return `nil` from `viewForFooterInSection:` in that case) and I want to be able to estimate the height (I am supporting Dynamic Text). My solution was to account for the code path that would give me a `0` height in `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:`. Once I added that, the exception went away.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug your

`(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

implementation. In my case it was returning a negative integer in some rare cases, resulting in the message showing up in my log and messing with the scrolling behavior of my table view.