# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints - UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

I recently added constraints to my prototype cell on a uitableview view and have run in to this warning when running my application (no errors but see this exception in the console log). I am adding objects to a mutable array dynamically based on specific conditions and inserting to the top of my uitableview. The insert rows also have variable heights.

The issue doesn't occur when I initialize an array with predetermined value, only when I add objects dynamically and push new view controllers.

I understand uitableview contains a scroll view and I have constrained the uitableview, but for some reason the error below says I have a scroll view constraint issue. I am not quite sure what it means.

All of my constraints were created using storyboard on Xcode 5. Dynamically changing height or the cell is done programmatically.

```
<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x17597a10 UITableView:0x18416000.contentHeight{id: 79} == -110.000000>"

)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

<_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint:0x17597a10 UITableView:0x18416000.contentHeight{id: 79} == -110.000000>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. I my case I solved it by returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the estimated row height, instead of a fixed number:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

I found the solution here: [Autolayout Error with UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397206/autolayout-error-with-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Same error with same circumstances, when i **changed** an entry of the MutableArray (_detailColumns). The error only appeared **once**, not at following changes!

I had included the Update in

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[[_detailColumns objectAtIndex:tag]setValue:textViewText forKey:@"content"];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

After removing **beginUpdates** and **endUpdates**, the message was gone (?!)